# Getting "replacement transaction underpriced" errors when sending Ethereum transactions to the Rinkeby network?

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, web3js

I'm getting intermittent "replacement transaction underpriced" errors on the Rinkeby network on the server side of my Node.JS dApp.  I am using the exact amount for estimated gas in my transaction send() call returned to me by the `estimateGas()` call.  In my call options, I am adding both a `gas` and `gasLimit` field just to be safe with the estimated gas value returned by `estimateGas()` in the `options` object.  Does anyone know how to fix this?

*On an unrelated issue.*  Much to my dismay, just submitting a transaction through Metamask to the Rinkeby network takes about 16 to 30 seconds.  Note, I mean from the time the Metamask extension pops up to the time my client side code regains control.  I am *not* talking about the time it takes to get a transaction confirmed/mined by the network.  Having said that, I am beginning to wonder if Metamask does not return control to you until the transaction has been mined.  Is that the case?

Here is a code fragment of the code I use to send the transaction to Rinkeby (or whatever network I'm testing on):

```
contractMethodToCall.estimateGas(
    { from: publicAddr, gasPrice: 20000000000, gas: 1500000})
.then(function(estimatedGas) {
    if (estimatedGas <= 0)
        throw new Error("The estimated gas for the transaction is zero.");

    const rawTx = {
        nonce: fromNonce,
        gasPrice: gasPriceGwei,
        // Use the estimated gas.
        gasLimit: estimatedGas,
        // Adding both gas and gasLimit just in case.
        gas: estimatedGas,
        to: contractAddr,
        value: '0x00',
        data: encodedAbiForCall
    }

    let tx = new Tx(rawTx);

    // Sign the transaction using our server private key in Buffer format.
    tx.sign(privateKeyBuffer);

    let serializedTx = '0x' + tx.serialize().toString('hex');

    return web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(serializedTx);
});
```

Comment: Maybe the transaction underpriced is because that transaction value is "0x00", also the function on your contract should be "payable".

Comment: @EduardoPereira It's an awkward error message.  The actual issue is a duplicate nonce.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you found the cause of your issue from your comment. But, to add clarity for others who see the same issue, the error is not solely because of a duplicate nonce. This error will occur when a transaction is submitted with a nonce that is already used in another pending transaction AND the gas price is the same (or less than) the pending transaction.

You can submit a transaction using the same nonce if you use a higher gas price. Miners will always pick the higher priced transaction for pending work, so this is a way to cancel a pending transaction or resubmit a transaction that is being ignored due to low gas prices.